# Refer to a Class from within a With VB.net

Tags: vb.net, initialization

I have called clientdetails which I wish to return as a whole to the JSONConvert Method to Serialize for JSON.

I have created a Class that has the Property Types I require (TextA,TextB) etc.

I can refer to both TransactionCount and TransactionType because they are part of ClientDetails, however when I try to refer to TextA of Transactions it states that TextA is not a member of ClientDetails - this I know which is why I explicitly state .Transactions.TextA.

If I declare Transactions separate under a new variable then I am able to refer to them however I need them to all be declared under ClientDetails to pass to the Serializer.

Can anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong here? Still learning.

```
Public Class JSON

Public Shared Function SerializeObject()

    Dim clientdetails As New ClientDetails() With {.TransactionCount = "1", .TransactionType = "Q", .Transactions.TextA} 'Unable to Refer to any Property of Transactions.

    'Dim Trans As New Transactions()

    'Trans.TextA= "Test"

    Dim output As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientdetails, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)

    Return output
End Function

End Class

Public Class ClientDetails
Public Property Transactions As New Transactions()
Public Property [TransactionType] As String
Public Property [TransactionCount] As Integer
End Class

Public Class Transactions

Public Property [RecordID] As String
Public Property No As String
Public Property TextA As String
Public Property TextB As String
Public Property Initial As String
Public Property Flag As String
Public Property Sex As String
Public Property Area As String
Public Property Type As String
Public Property IDNO As String

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
Dim clientdetails As New ClientDetails() With {.TransactionCount = "1", .TransactionType = "Q", .Transactions = New Transactions() With {.TextA = "Test"}}
```

Or a more readable code:

```
Dim trans As New Transactions
trans.TextA = "Test"

Dim clientDetails As New ClientDetails()

With clientDetails
    .TransactionCount = "1"
    .TransactionType = "Q"
    .Transactions = trans
End With
```

Comment: Much appreciated bud, knew I was going wrong somewhere.